Find all the square natural numbers $x$ such that $|x-10!|=x-10!$ and $|x-11!|=11!-x$
Book's original problem:

Find all the square natural numbers $x$ such that $|x-10!|=x-10!$ and $|x-11!|=11!-x$

I have an original book's answer, but I can not understand .
The book says $10!\le x \le 11!$. Let $A=2^8\cdot3^4\cdot 5^2$ so we have that $A\cdot7\le x\le A\cdot 77$ so $x\in\{A\cdot3^2,A\cdot 4^2,A\cdot5^2, A\cdot 6^2, A\cdot 7^2,A\cdot8^2\}$
My problem.
How do we know that $x+N$ for some $N$ can not be a perfect square, which $A\not\mid x$ .
I feel like something goes wrong in book's solution, if not I can not fully understand that solution, unfortunately. I need your help please to understand what is going on.

Note that $|u|= u$ when $u\ge0$ and $|u|=-u$ when $u\le0$

This just means find all $n^2$ with $10!\leq n^2\leq 11!$ which easily yields $\sqrt {10!}\leq n\leq\sqrt{11!}.$

@Soheil I know ...

What does this question have to do with prime factors?

@ThomasAndrews Maybe I expressed    my question wrong.

So, um... in other words, you just want to find all $x$ so that $10! \le x^2 \le 11!$.  $|x -M = x-M \iff x-M \ge 0 \iff x \ge M$ and $|x-K| = K-x \iff x-K \le 0 \iff x \le K$.  It seems to me that this is a really convoluted and confusing  way to state a really simple concept.

You didn't express it "wrong".  But does seem unnecessarily obfuscated.

Hard to tell if you expressed it wrong. The question makes sense, but some of the additional comments are confusing, given the question you asked.

@ThomasAndrews Is Book's solution really correct ?

Actually... I think your book expressed it weirdly. Is it ever mentioned we are only allowed primes less than $10$???

Okay... It really seems like the book is answering a very different question that was asked. The answer to $10! \le x =n^2 \le 11^2$ is simply $x=n^2: \sqrt{10!}\approx 1904.9 < n < \sqrt{11!}\approx 6317.9$.  But the next steps seems to imply we are restricted to only prime factors less than $10$ and none of them to any higher powers than occur in $10!$.  If that's a requirement the book should have stated so in stating it in the problem.   Actually stating a problem where that is the answer might be a challenge.

.. on third though:  The book is just wrong.  It correctly states that $7A < x < 77A$ but incorrectly assume for utterly no reason we are only considering multiples of $A$.  We aren't.  If I wrotel  $7\cdot 19 < x < 23 \cdot 19$ that will include $8\cdot 19$ and $9\cdot 19$ etc but it also includes numbers that are not multiples of $19$ of course (such as $15\cdot 19 + 7$, etc).  ... It's an astonishingly naive statement for a text to make.

The book's answer seems to imply it is answering a different question, though I can't say what that question is.

@ThomasAndrews I'm not so sure.  It depends on what "the book" is.  It sort of seems like a students failed attempt at a solution to this which could be a really really amateurish book.  I can see making the mistake of see $7 A \le x \le 77A;$ and $x$ is square and think "oh, we are going from $7A$ to $77A$ and taking the square so that $3^2A,4^2A, 5^2,.... 8^2A$.   I mean its careless and really really sloppy but... So what is this "book"?  I find the bit of $|A-B|=A-B|$ and $|C-B|=B-C$ to be equally dubious and clunky.

So the book correctly points out that $10! \le x \le 11!$ and that if $A= 2^83^45^2$ then $10! = 7A \le x \le 77A = 11!$.
So for so good.
But then they mistakenly assume that because we wrote this as $7A \le x \le 77A$ we are only considering the multiples of $A$.  (!Why!). The book is correct that as $A = (2^43^2\cdot 5)^2$ is a perfect squares the only other perfect squares that are multiples of $A$ are $3^2A, 4^2A, 5^2A,6^2,7^2A$, and $8^2 A$.
But we aren't considering only multiples of $A$ of course!  So the answer is wrong.
Instead if $x = n^2$ and $7A \le n^2 \le 77A$ then $\sqrt{7A} \le n \le \sqrt{77A}$.
$A=2^83^45^2 = (720)^2$.  $\sqrt{7A} = 720\times \sqrt 7 \approx 1904.9$ and $\sqrt{77A}= 720\times \sqrt{77}\approx 6317.9$.
So we just want $x = n^2 $ where $1905\le n \le 6317$.
That's all there is to it.
(On a side note, its a bad idea to use variable $x$ or $A$ for a number known to be a square number and whose only point is that they are a square number.  If $x$ must be a square include it in the declaration of the variable.  "Let $n^2$ be the square of a natural number, $n$, so that $|n^2-10!|= n^2-10!$ and $|n^2-11!|=11! - n^2$" and "As $2^83^45^2$ is a perfect square let $B=2^43^25$ so $B^2=2^83^45^2$ and $10! = 7B^2$ and $11!=77B^2$.
(Then when you do your manipultations:
$10^2 = 7B^2 \le n^2 \le 77B^2 = 11^2$
(The path:
$\sqrt 7B \le n \le 77B$
$\sqrt7\cdot 2^43^2\cdot 5 \le n \le \sqrt{77}2^43^2\cdot 5$
$720\sqrt 7\le n \le 720\sqrt{77}$
(should become much more apparent.)

What do you think about book's original solution ???

I'm perplexed by the books solution.  It seems it is requiving that $720^2= A$ must be a factor of $x$ rather than $x$ can by any perfect square.  Which is fine if the book stated that was part of the problem.  I don't think the book expressed the problem correctly.

Don't use $!$ as punctuation, especially after a variable name, especially in a problem involving factorials.

Also, $\sqrt{7A}$ is not approximately $720\sqrt7,$ it is equal.

Yeah, I worried about the exclamation point.  And the approximate wasn't about the $720\sqrt 7$, it was about the $1904.9$.  Got lost in my editis.
